# When are empty organisation accounts cleared up?

Tags: github

There are many empty organisation accounts on GitHub (e.g. [organisation](https://github.com/organisation)) which takes just a name, but their repositories are empty, so they're not useful at all. Is there any point of time when they get removed? If it's not done automatically, it is fine to report an abuse, because of that?

Comment: What abuse is there for having an empty list of repos?

Comment: Some companies will create GitHub organizations as a reserve so that, in the future when they do begin to use GitHub, they are sure their name will be available.